# Java: Increasing heap size in Windows doesn't take effect

Tags: java, memory, windows-7, heap-memory

I run the following code from command line:

```
public class MemoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long maxMb = rt.maxMemory()/(1024*1024);
        System.out.println("Your JVM will use up to " + maxMb + " MB of memory for its heap");
    }

}
```

It outputs: *247 MB*

I then go to the **Java** icon in the Control Panel -> Java tab -> View -> Runtime Parameters column.
I enter the following: *-Xms512M -Xmx1024M*

Then I run the memory test again. Output: *247 MB*.

Why doesn't it increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running java from the command line, you need to specify it on the command line

Try

```
java -mx1g MemoryTest
```

Comment: Yeah I think the Control Panel settings only apply when you do things like double-click JAR files to run them.

Comment: Would the Control Panel setting also affect applets in browser?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @R.V. Probably, it would make sense.